# Reading a text file line by line using java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have had two years experience in Java but have not touched in a year therefore a little rusty.

I am trying to reading a text file line by line using Java8 (the new way).

Based on a forum I have read I am using the following code:

```
package codeTest;

import java.io.IOException; 
import java.nio.file.Files; 
import java.nio.file.Paths; 
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filename = "RouterInfo.txt";

        try(Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename))) {
            stream.forEach(System.out::println);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But no matter what I try I keep getting a `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException`.

Here is a picture of my file directory in eclipse:

[image]

Can anybody help?

Comment: Sorry for bothering anyone who is answering my question above. But I have just realised I had put the text file in the wrong place.

Comment: Then consider posting the answer (where it should be or what you changed), or accepting an answer is there already is one below.

Answer (score 0):

Your text file is in src/codeTest folder so it should be

```
"src/codeTest/RouterInfo.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Java code is correct. Only your `RouterInfo.txt` is in the wrong place. Just put it into your project directory instead of into `src`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `filename` string with `"./src/RounterInfo.txt"`.

Answer (score 0):

The text file should not be put in the src folder but in the folder that contains src.

Therefore the new folder path should be:

Answer/sample.txt

Answer would be the name of the folder containing src.